# How can you programatically export a receive location?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

How can you programatically export a BizTalk receive location?

*And extending the question ...* receive ports and send ports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to approach this, each with benefits and drawbacks.

1. WMI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547992.aspx 
   The drawback is this is by Assembly, so you'd have to enumerate them first.
2. BTSTask.exe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559686.aspx Better, since it allows you to specify an Assembler or an Application.  There's no object model, but executing from another program or script works fine.
3. PowerShell Provider for BizTalk: http://psbiztalk.codeplex.com/
   The way to go if you're scripting in PowerShell already.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to export the bindings to an xml file and import them in your target environment. This article outlines the steps...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560753.aspx

Further if you are going to be doing deployments to multiple environments you should look at the BizTalk Deployment Framework...
http://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/